# Cast binary to enum in python for redis conversion

Tags: python, enums, redis

I am storing an enum in redis.  When I load it, the value is in binary.  Howe can I cast it to be a python enum?

Example code:

```
class Position(Enum):
    LEFT = 10
    RIGHT = 11

current_position = Position.LEFT
r.set('current_position', Position.LEFT)
loaded_current_position = r.get('current_position_side') 

print(current_position) # Position.LEFT
print(loaded_current_position) # b'Position.LEFT'
```

In this example, I'd like to get `loaded_current_position` to equal `Position.LEFT` not `b'Position.LEFT'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's being stored is the name of the Enum member.  There may be a redis specific answer, but in general you can mix your Enum with another data type, such as `int`, and then cast it back to an Enum upon retrieval; something like:

```
class Position(int, Enum):
    LEFT = 10
    RIGHT = 11

current_position = Position.LEFT
r.set('current_position', Position.LEFT)
loaded_current_position = Position(r.get('current_position_side'))

print(current_position) # Position.LEFT
print(loaded_current_position) # Position.LEFT
```

Note:  for the above to work, redis must save and return an `int`

Comment: Yea I also tried IntEnum - https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Your method seems even simpler

Comment: In my example, `Position` is basically an `IntEnum`.